# Are letters from MPs to other MPs on the internet?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament, member-of-parliament

I read a letter from the Prime Minister to another MP on some website, and I want to read the MPs letter in response (if there was one). Is there a database of letters that MPs send to each other? I'm assuming these things are public, but I've searched and I can't find any.

Comment: Are these some kind of official letters, sent as part of government business, or just personal correspondence?

Comment: Are you referring to any particular MP and their letter? It might be helpful to include that.

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica FYI, I was looking for Corbyn's response to Johnsons letter to Corbyn about a second referendum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; your assumption that such letters are public is mistaken. There's no statutory requirement to publish correspondence between MPs. Although the House of Commons *is* a public body under the Freedom of Information Act, individual MPs [are not](https://www.parliament.uk/site-information/foi/foi-and-eir/commons-foi-eir-information/), and thus there's no legislative framework to compel them to publish correspondence. Individual MPs, particularly if they are government ministers, may and do choose to publish correspondence, but it's entirely at their discretion.

Answer (score -1):

They are in an envelope and private unless published. Civil service email is also generally private.

Correspondance guidelines, other than basic FOI and environment FOI acts, if there are any, are given by the whips and party communications staff. Rees Mogg started his current post by issuing strict instructions for correspondance etiquette.

Comment: Anyone can log an FOI request, it takes literally seconds. Any request for information from a public body is generally interpreted as a FOI request even if the Act is not specifically mentioned. Even an email as short as "Please send me X" qualifies as an FOI request.

Comment: Ok the MP mail protocol including FOI is generally written in guidelines given by the party leadership, things like obligation to reply to other MP letters.

Comment: Not sure I understand that last comment

Comment: Correspondance guidelines, other than FOI and environment FOI acts, if there are any, are given by the whips and party communications staff. Rees Mogg started his current post by issuing strict instructions for correspondance etiquette.